# First person controls in autodesk-viewer forge api

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

Can the autodesk-viewer first person controls be tuned in the user api?  The defaults are pretty slow and the first person "orientation drag mode" does not keep up with the mouse.  I would experiment with making the defaults a little snappier even if it means the large model render can't keep up right away.

Comment: also the default key assignments for Q and E are unintuitive.  (I would expect something like space bar instead of Q for up and shift or S instead of E  for down,  the current shift speed should be default, or even faster)

Answer (score 0):

This is available at the [Viewer3D object](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v2/reference/javascript/viewer3d/) but also as a default [First Person extension](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v2/reference/javascript/firstpersonextension/).

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to customize directly the parameters used by this extension, but you can take a look at the source code in the [viewer3D.js](https://autodeskviewer.com/viewers/2.8/viewer3D.js) file and create your own. The extension itself doesn't do much except activating FirstPersonTool, look for ***Autodesk.Viewing.Extensions.FirstPerson.FirstPersonTool*** (L83752). Once you have your own tool and extension, you can eventually replace the control in the UI to activate it instead of the native one.